# RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required while installing the python libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am using a virtual environment.
In that I am having a python version `3.7.0`

```
virtualenv --python=python3.7 .env
```

Now, whenever I am trying to install any library over there ,it is giving me this error

```
Downloading/unpacking scikit-learn==0.20.2
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pycharm-packaging421/scikit-learn/setup.py) egg_info for package scikit-learn
    Partial import of sklearn during the build process.

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from scikit-learn==0.20.2)
Downloading/unpacking scipy>=0.13.3 (from scikit-learn==0.20.2)
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pycharm-packaging421/scipy/setup.py) egg_info for package scipy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging421/scipy/setup.py", line 31, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("Python version >= 3.5 required.")
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging421/scipy/setup.py", line 31, in <module>

    raise RuntimeError("Python version >= 3.5 required.")

RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.
```

can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Is Python 3.7 installed on your system? What happens when you activate the environment and run `python --version`, does it actually show 3.7?

Comment: Yes I have installed it.

Answer (score 0):

To use `virtualenv` in older version of python3 use this method.

Create:
`python3 -m venv .venv`

Activate:
`source .venv/bin/activate`

Exit:
`deactivate`

I test it on Python 3.4.2 in Debian 8.11